# S3 signature mismatch with Amazon::S3 perl

Tags: perl, amazon-s3, authorization, signature

When I try to generate the request header along with the signature, I'm getting a signature mismatch error.

I used Amazon::S3 Perl module to generate the request. And when analyzed the difference in approach on how the signature is calculated between this module and AWS CLI, I found out that when I comment out the below line from S3.pm inside _make_request() method, makes the signature matches.

```
$self->_add_auth_header($http_headers, $method, $path)
      unless exists $headers->{Authorization};
```

Am I referring it correctly or is there any other module I can use just for generating the signature alone or at the last option, I can write my own module which inherits the actual module (if possible or mimic the actual module with the custom change).

Comment: show your code that's generating the request/signature?

Comment: I am facing signature mismatch issue when singing my HTTPS requests with V4. 

`<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>AXXXXXXXXXXXXXXQXXXX</AWSAccessKeyId><StringToSign>AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 20181015T075241Z 20181015/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request 47d80c227b12680c22a13d486415c0299a180c2a41e85cd63c9b294a8e4180c2</StringToSign><SignatureProvided>df2280c2611318c2df926b20080c2dcabe80c278c987e3dedba75880c2c305a0</SignatureProvided>`

Comment: I've used the Amazon::S3 module to create request and used Net::Amazon::Signature::V4 module to sign the request header. When I comment out the above two lines from S3.pm _make_request(), the signature actually matches.

Comment: @ysth Please let me know if any other information is required. Thanks!

Comment: if you provide a runnable script (obscuring any private information like keys) showing exactly what you are doing more people will at least look at your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve